# v-html in VueJS is not working (empty page)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

I am new to VueJS and I am trying to display a local html-file inside of the Vue Application.

Example html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello World</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I did some research and I heard that an easy way to do that is to load the file via axios and display the result. So I did that like following:

```
<div v-html="contentdisplay"></div>
```

```
<script> 
import axios from 'axios'

export default { 

  data() { 
    return { 
      input: null
      }
  }, 

 created() {
 this.loadFile()
 },

 computed: {
   contentdisplay: function() {
   return this.input;
   }
 },

 methods: {
        loadFile() {
          axios({
            method: "get",
            url: "../../test.html"
          })
            .then(result => {
              this.input = result.data;
              console.log("Data: " + result.data)
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.error("error getting file: " + error);
            });
        },
      }
}

</script>
```

The Example.html works fine, but when I try to load the real file, I don't see anything. This file contains
`<script type="text/javascript" ... </script>`
and 
`<script type="application/json"> ... </script>`

I don't get any error messages and the console log with result.data is showing the correct html, but Vue is not showing me anything. What should I adjust to make this work?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you could add a `:key="refresh"` to your v-html div and do `refresh+=1` after setting input and see if that works

Comment: Did a quick test and for me it works. Should be no different in your case when you are able to log the HTML in the console. Do you use the vue-cli?

Comment: Yes I used vue-cli and now I got it to work with the "Hello World"-Example but when I try to load the real html, I don't see anything ... The html is generated from Bokeh and contains <script type="text/javascript"> and <script type="application/json"> ... do you have an idea what I have to adjust to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do:

```html
<div v-html="input"></div>
```

Comment: Yup, no need for computed properties here. But both cases will work!

Comment: Yes it worked, but I edited the question, it's a different problem now. Thanks for your help

Comment: It's not good practice to just edit the question to a new one as it ruins the point of stackoverflow. The best thing to do is to create a new question in this case

Answer (score 0):

You dont't need to use computed property for this, just use `v-html="input"`.
For example i have made some changes in your code:

```
<div v-html="input"></div>
```

```
<script> 
import axios from 'axios'

export default { 

  data() { 
    return { 
      input: null
      }
  }, 

 created() {
 this.loadFile()
 },

 methods: {
        loadFile() {
          axios({
            method: "get",
            url: "../../test.html"
          })
            .then(result => {
              this.input = result.data;
              console.log("Data: " + result.data)
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.error("error getting file: " + error);
            });
        },
      }
}

</script>
```

Your `res.data` should be a proper html for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.1/axios.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <div v-html="input"></div>   
    </div>
    <script>
        new Vue({
            el:"#app",
            data: { 
                input: null    
            }, 
            created() {
                this.loadFile()
            },
            methods: {
                loadFile() {
                    axios({
                        method: "get",
                        url: "https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt"
                    })
                    .then(result => {
                        this.input = result.data;                        
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error("error getting file: " + error);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```